# Swift - create individual UIView for each cell in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` where the user can add `cells` to it. By adding a `cell` a `customView` should be added to that specific cell which the user can access by tapping on the `cell`.

I've tried different things now but I can not make it work...

At the moment I am trying to declare the `UIView` ("CustomWishlistView") inside my `cell` like this:

```
    class ContentCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    lazy var theCustomWishlistView: CustomWishlistView = {
        let v = CustomWishlistView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .darkGray
        v.layer.cornerRadius = 30
        return v
    }()

    let buttonView: UIButton = {
        let v = UIButton()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        v.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1.5, height: 1.5)
        v.layer.shadowRadius = 3
        v.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        return v
    }()

    let theLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.textAlignment = .center
        return v
    }()

    let testLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.text = "Test Label"
        v.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 18)
        v.textColor = .darkGray
        v.textAlignment = .center
        return v
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }


    func commonInit() -> Void {

        contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0;
        contentView.addSubview(testLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(buttonView)
        // constrain label to all 4 sides
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([


            buttonView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
            buttonView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            buttonView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
            buttonView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:150),

            testLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonView.bottomAnchor,constant: 1),
            testLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
            testLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            testLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
        ])
        buttonView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(customWishlistTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    var customWishlistTapCallback: (() -> ())?

       @objc func customWishlistTapped(_ sender: Any) {
           // tell the collection view controller we got a button tap
            customWishlistTapCallback?()
       }
}
```

A `cell` gets added to my `UICollectionView` in this function where the user can also set a custom `Image` and `Label`:

```
func createListButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        // "Liste erstellen" button was tapped
        self.appDidEnterBackgroundHandler()

        if let txt = listNameTextfield.text {

            self.newListTextfield.resignFirstResponder()

            // append user-entered text to the data array
            self.theData.append(txt)
            self.imageData.append(self.image!)


            let cell = ContentCell()
            let theCustomWishlistView = cell.theCustomWishlistView

            self.view.addSubview(theCustomWishlistView)
            // constrain CustomWishlistView
            theCustomWishlistView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 120.0).isActive = true
            theCustomWishlistView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            theCustomWishlistView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 30.0).isActive = true
            theCustomWishlistView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -30.0).isActive = true
            theCustomWishlistView.wishlistImage.image = self.image
            theCustomWishlistView.wishlistLabel.text = txt
            theCustomWishlistView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 1000)

            self.view.bringSubviewToFront(containerView)


            // reload the collection view
            theCollectionView.reloadData()
            theCollectionView.performBatchUpdates(nil, completion: {
                (result) in
                // scroll to make newly added row visible (if needed)
                let i = self.theCollectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) - 1
                let idx = IndexPath(item: i, section: 0)
                self.theCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: idx, at: .bottom, animated: true)

                // close (hide) the "New List" view
                self.closeButtonTappedNewList(nil)
            })
        }
    }
```

My `func cellForItemAt` for my `CollectionView` is where I handle the `customWishlistCallback()` to let the `customWishlistView` appear.

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ContentCell", for: indexPath) as! ContentCell

        cell.testLabel.text = theData[indexPath.item - 1]

        cell.buttonView.setImage(imageData[indexPath.item - 1], for: .normal)

    cell.customWishlistTapCallback = {
        // let wishlistView appear
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
            cell.theCustomWishlistView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
        })
        // let welcomeText disappear
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.welcomeTextLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
        })
    }
       return cell
   }
```

The code above is not working. Tapping no my `cell` does not let a `UIView` appear. I am stuck on this problem for days now and I just can not figure it out. I am really grateful for any kind of help!

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://medium.com/infancyit/callbacks-in-swift-a-practical-example-with-tableview-and-collectionview-5b6e79edef4 ?

Comment: I looked at it but I do not see how I can apply this to my setup :/ Thanks anyway

Comment: Why are you using a callback instead of a `UITapGestureRecognizer`?

Comment: callback is working quite good for me. If you want to have a look at my project so get a better idea of it, here is my git: https://github.com/chriskonnerth/Wishlist

Comment: Why do you say callback is working quite good, but you are not seeing your view to appear? Did you step through your code, is `theCustomWishlistView` created properly? Maybe try it without the animation first.

Comment: I have a cell, that is always in my `collectionView`. And I use callback inside of it to let a `View` appear. That is working perfectly fine. My problem is that I "hardcoded" that `View` and now I am trying to implemented it in another way so I can create a new `View` for each time I create a new `cell` . It is kind of hard to explain. You can just run my code and then you'll know what I mean

Comment: It's recommended to share all the relevant code here and provide an [example] to demonstrate your problem instead of linking to a complete project elsewhere.

Comment: @Chris - your code is not doing anything unless the "main wishlist" cell or the "Add" cell is selected. What you want to do is set the data for your wishlist when the corresponding cell is selected. (it is a bit difficult to test your app... I created an account, but running it a second time fails the password check, and no way to know why or how to fix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create separate views for each "Wish List"

The general idea will be:

- create a data manager class, that will hold an array of "Wish Lists"
- each wish list will have a name, image id, and a list of "Wishes"
- when the user selects an existing list:

  - set the title in the wish list view
  - set the image in the wish list view
  - set the data for the wish table view to the wish list data associated with that wish list
  - call `.reloadData()` on the table view
  - show the updated wish list view

When the user creates a new "Wish List" and adds / removes "Wishes" from that list, update the data in the array of Wish Lists

So, a couple significant changes to your existing code...

- You don't need different "Main" and "Custom" collection view cells. Create a "Main Wish List" and set it as the first element in the array of lists. You can then treat it the same as a custom list.
- Use protocol / delegate pattern to allow the wish list view to tell the main controller to update the list of wishes (when one is deleted, for example).

It is a bit difficult to work with your app (from GitHub) right now, as it doesn't save or retrieve any data yet, but I made various changes that *should* get you headed in the right direction.

There is too much to include everything here as an answer, so I posted the 3 changed files here: https://gist.github.com/DonMag/1bab48ea53b26419d59de635e7692e4b

As before, look for comments -- this time, beginning with `// DonMag3 -`. I included the ***entire*** class files so don't have to pick-and-choose what to update.

Comment: ok. what you just did here is awesome! You are helping me a lot. I will read though all the code later, will probably have some questions about it, but till then I can just thank you:)

Comment: ok, I think saving/retrieving data is my top priority task for now as it would make the rest a lot easier. In your code you just simulated the data from a server. How would I realize that? In the end the user should be able to use the app online AND offline and it should basically work like in the app "Todoist". Do you know where I should start on that?

Comment: never mind. I think Firebase Firestore will do the job

Comment: it's me again :D I worked quite a bit and I connected my app with the Cloud Firestore DB. Everything was working fine but now I a trying to retrieve the wishes and append it to each list but it is not working and I don't really get how exactly `insertWish` works that you implemented. Here is my git: https://github.com/chriskonnerth/Wishlist  The function I am working on is inside `DataHandler` ->  `func getWishes()` . Would really appreciate your help here!:)

Comment: @Chris - see changes to your `getWishes()` func here https://pastebin.com/deC1bcqw ... that will populate the main `userWishListData` array. It looks, though, like you are not saving the new wishes to the proper wish list.

Comment: I decided to subclass the `wishlistView` which makes the code a lot cleaner. The problem right now is that `insertWish` works weird. It inserts the wishes correctly but if I restart the app and retrieve data the wishes are in the wrong `wishlists`. Retrieving wishes worked perfectly fine before so it has somethings to do with the subclassing but I don't know what. Another things is that I can not really `deleteWish` because if I close and open the `wishlist` the wish I just deleted appears again in the list.  `insertWish` is still in the `MainVC` but `deleteWish` is now in `WishlistVC`

Comment: I just updated my git. You already how much I appreciate your help :D Happy Holidays!